com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host , port 1071 has failed. Error: "Connect time out
I am upgrading my project from java 8 to 21 and springboot 2.x to 3.x, I am getting this error while connecting to microsoft server database.
Stack trace:
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The TCP/IP connection to the host xyz,  port 1071 has failed. Error: "Connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar!/:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar!/:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar!/:1.4]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:160) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:118) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:388) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:476) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:486) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at 


port 1071 is kind of a strange port to connect for sql server. Are you sure you're using sql server? what does your connection string look like

this is the connection string : 1071 in not the actual port that is just for reference purpose :
jdbc:sqlserver://somehost.com:10504;DatabaseName=TestDb;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True

Strange, sounds like you did more than upgrade java, since the error is a network one? Is that port open on that host?

yes , port is open, it was connecting before java & spring upgradation. seems like some security conditions has increased in newer version

Please follow this step and check.

Open Control Panel > System And Security > Windows Defender Firewall > `Advanced Settings

Click on Inbound Rules > New Rules




Select Port from the option



Select TCP and specified the Port No Or Select All Local Ports



Other setting as it is and give name of your rule and save
Follow Same Process For the Outbound Rules

TCP Configuration In SQL Server Configuration Manager

Open SQL Server Configuration Manager
Go to SQL Server Network Configuration
And Select Server Instance From the list
Select TCP/IP and go to the IP Addresses
Check the TCP Port
Enabled the TCP/IP Property


